# Response from db is offset, not all results returned using map function

Tags: node.js, view, couchdb, cloudant

Why is `offset: 1`?

I'm expecting to see 2 `rows` in the response from `Cloudant`, as `total_rows` indicates, but its offset for some reason so only 1 row is present in response.

Console output:

```
{ total_rows: 2,
  offset: 1,
  rows: 
   [ { id: '1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c883d496',
       key: '1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c883d496',
       value: [Object] } ] }
```

Calling the function, handle response:

```
viewImpl('test', 'something').then(function(result) {

  result.rows.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.value);
  });

  res.status(200).send('done');
  }
}).catch(someFunc());
```

Function def:

```
App.prototype.viewImpl = function(designName, viewName) {
  return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    _this.db.view(designName, viewName, { keys: ["1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c883d496","1e0ad30d18d95b9bcc05d92c883e272"] }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        fulfill(result);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

View defined in `Cloudant`:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc._id, { _id: doc._id, _rev: doc._rev, some_field: doc.some_field });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the keys provided to the `view()` function:

```
1e0a2d30d18d95b9bcc05d92c883d496
1e0ad30d18d95b9bcc05d92c883e272
```

The second key is one character shorter - it's just 31 characters instead of 32. I guess you just missed the last character when copy pasting it from document ID.

Remove the keys parameters to see all rows, then check what is the correct key for the second row and update your code.